# How to return a value from if-statement into a function golang

Tags: python, go, difference

I had a problem when I started to use Golang after Python. In Python, a variable that is declared inside an if-statement will be visible for a function/method if the statement is inside the function.

```
from pydantic import BaseModel

class sometype(BaseModel):
    """
    A model describes new data structure which will be used
    """
    sometype1: str

def someaction(somedata:sometype):
    """
    do some action
    :param somedata: a sometype instance
    :return:
    """
    print("%s" % somedata.sometype1 )

def somefunc(somedata:int, somebool:bool, anydata:sometype):
    """
    It is a function
    :param somedata: some random int
    :param somebool: thing that should be True (else there will be an error)
    :param anydata: sometype instance
    :return:
    """
    if somebool==True:
        somenewdata=anydata
    someaction(somenewdata)

if __name__=="__main__":
    print("some")
    thedata :sometype = sometype(sometype1="stringtypedata")
    somefunc(1, True, thedata)
```

An IDE only can warn you ("Local variable '...' might be referenced before assignment") that this could not be referenced in some cases (to be precise - there will be no variable named "somenewdata" if the "somebool" be False).
[image: example of an IDE warning]

When I tried to do something similar in Go - I couldn't use the variable outside if-statement.

```
// main package for demo
package main

import "fmt"

//sometype organizes dataflow
type sometype struct {
    sometype1 string
}

//someaction does action
func someaction(somedata sometype) {
    fmt.Printf("%v", somedata)
}

//somefunc is a function
func somefunc(somedata int, somebool bool, anydata sometype) {
    if somebool == true {
        somenewdata = anydata
    }
    someaction(somenewdata)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("some")
    thedata := sometype{"stringtype"}
    somefunc(1, true, thedata)

}
```

This error ("Unresolved reference "..."") will appear in IDE and the code will not compile.
My question was - why does that happening?
Upvote if you had the same issue.
[image: Golang error description]

Comment: The better question IMO is why does python allow this.

Comment: If you want to use if statements as an expression then consider the ternary operator.

Comment: @super, I suppose, because it is an interpretable language.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

I struggled with this problem as I didn't realise that it was implied that the variable which is used inside if-function is not visible for a function.

The answer is simple - you don't need to return the value in this case as you should just fill the value. So, you need to introduce it before the if-statement inside the function, and it will be visible for both: the function and the statement.

Upvote if the answer resolved your issue.

```
// main package for demo
package main

import "fmt"

//sometype organizes dataflow
type sometype struct {
    sometype1 string
}

//someaction does action
func someaction(somedata sometype) {
    fmt.Printf("%v", somedata)
}

//somefunc is a function
func somefunc(somedata int, somebool bool, anydata sometype) {
    //introduce the variable
    var somenewdata sometype 
    if somebool == true {
        //fill the variable with data
        somenewdata = anydata
    }
    someaction(somenewdata)
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("some")
    thedata := sometype{"stringtype"}
    somefunc(1, true, thedata)

}
```

Comment: If you downwoting, please, make a comment.